# OAuth 2.0 Authorized JavaScript origins localhost

Tags: google-oauth

I get an error using Google OAuth 2.0 when I click on the Google SignIn button from my localhost test server.  The same error does not occur when I try it from production server.

The error is:

> 400. That's an error.
>
> **Error: invalid request**

According to the Google documentation, you need to specify the authorized JavaScript origins, which I did:

> `http://myproductionsite.com`  (works)
>
> `http://localhost:80` (doesn't work)
>
> `http://localhost` (doesn't work)

For my test server, I am using apache 2.4.2